# Identity not working after publish IsAuthenticated is false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

my problem is `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` but i have success result login

note that this problem only after publishing to IIS but in the visual studio run no problems
and the web site working fine! how come?

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, false, lockoutOnFailure: true);
```

any idea any solution anything helps me? please

Comment: Do you mean the result is success in the IIS but the User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false? I suggest you could try to use F12 develop tool's network to check the request to make sure the identity cookie has been set well,

Comment: @BrandoZhang there is no errors in inspector
any way i solve it 

yes it's a strange problem and a strange solution

you have to give IIS_IUSRS Full Permission on the main folder and for each subfolder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution
yes it's a strange problem and a strange solution

you have to give IIS_IUSRS Full Permission on the main folder and for each subfolder.